# only foreign key id retrive when i pass model instance to form but i want other field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i am new in django, i have a problem with instance when pass it in form. Because my instance has 10 field including 3 foreign key field.
when i pass instance to the form in views, i only see that the foreign key field attribute only retrive their id only but i want to retrive other field from foreign key table.
If it possible please help me.

this is the model which i use as instance to pass through form

```
class CreateMasterBet(models.Model):
     owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='owner')
     opposite = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, 
     related_name='opposite')
     ownerTeam = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
     oppositeTeam = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
     match = models.ForeignKey(Match)
     ownerProposedRate = models.IntegerField()
     ownerProposedRateForOpposite = models.IntegerField()
     betis = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='open')
     howMany = models.IntegerField(default=1)
     time = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.owner) + "( " + str(self.ownerTeam) + " )"
```

the forms for this model instance is below:

```
class BetEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
          owner = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Owner', 
                'class': 'form-control'}))
          opposite = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Opposite', 
                'class': 'form-control'}))
          ownerTeam = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Owner Team', 
                'class': 'form-control'}))
          oppositeTeam = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Opposite 
                Team', 'class': 'form-control'}))
          match = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False,  
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Match', 
                'class': 'form-control'}))
          ownerProposedRate = forms.IntegerField(required=False, 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Owner need 
                to pay', 'class': 'form-control'}))
          ownerProposedRateForOpposite = 
                forms.IntegerField(required=False, 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Opposite 
                team pay me', 'class': 'form-control'}))
          betis = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False, 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Bet Status', 
                'class': 'form-control'}))
          howMany = forms.IntegerField(required=False, 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Number of 
                Bets', 'class': 'form-control'}))
          time = forms.DateTimeField(required=False, 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Match Played 
                At', 'class': 'form-control'}))

          class Meta:
               model = CreateMasterBet
               fields = ('owner', 'opposite', 'ownerTeam', 'oppositeTeam', 
                         'match', 'ownerProposedRate', 
                         'ownerProposedRateForOpposite', 'betis', 
                         'howMany', 'time')
```

in views.py i pass the model instance in the form ;

```
instance = CreateMasterBet.objects.get(id=betid)
form = BetEditForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
```

then in template i only see the corresponding foreign key fields only retrive id , but in this place i want to retrive other information from foreign key table

[image link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4m-tBXP7BN0Z0tMWkJNN3JqNzQ)

in this image 1st 2 field are shown just foreign key. But i want here to retrive other value from foreign key table

please help, if you know how to do it.
thanks in advance

Comment: Your image link doesn't work (Error 404)

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4m-tBXP7BN0Z0tMWkJNN3JqNzQ      please check it now

Comment: Thomas Fritsch check it